# Angular 6 Failing To Load Images From Assets

Tags: html, angular, image, http-status-code-404, assets

For some reason I can't get my images to show in my app.
This is the error, tests and class:

```
The error: GET http://localhost:4200/assets/image.png 404 (Not Found)

<img class="logo" src="../../assets/image.png">
<img class="logo" src="../assets/image.png">
<img class="logo" src="assets/image.png">
//None of these work

.logo {
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Any idea why this is not working? My image.png is in my assets folder which is located at src/assets/image.png.

Update:

So we did a test. We copied all the node modules and the project files to another pc and there the images loaded correctly. So I assume the problem lies outside the angular project it self.

Comment: The problem still persists on the latest versions of angular but it normally goes away by itself after restarting the server. always be remember to check and add the assets folder into the assets path in Angular.json file.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
<img class="logo" src="assets/image.png">
```

This is the right path, probably something else went wrong.

check that the image name or if its jpeg. 
maybe you added a new folder in the assets folder ? , like images if so the code should look like this

```
<img class="logo" src="assets/image/image.png">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I definitely have the right extension and the right path. The image is a .png right inside the assets folder (no extra folder inside there)

Comment: Why is this the selected answer when it didn't answer your question (as you say in the above comment)?

Answer (score 34):

Add assets folder to your angular.json.

```
"assets": [
    "src/assets"
 ],
```

Then refer the images like below,

```
<img src="/assets/image.png">
```

This should work.

Comment: This is likely the right answer to the CANNOT GET error message.

Comment: Thank you. Been fighting this for awhile!

Comment: If you changed the "assets" property in angular.json, don't forget to RELOAD THE APP with ng serve.

Answer (score 9):

`src="assets/image.png"` should work without issue. Have you restarted your build since you added in the image?

Comment: By "restarted the build" do you mean restarting the ng serve? Yes I have, I have turned off my pc multiple times while working on the project.

Comment: I am adding image in `src\assets\images` in this but image not display in angular but after recompile app it will show for same path I have used before, please suggest me

Answer (score 7):

> The folder which contains your assets (like pictures) needs to be
>   declared in **assets** array inside your angular.json

Angular only recognizes those assets which have been declared in angular.json or the assets which come from web.

Additionally, from all the three options following will work for you:-

```
<img class="logo" src="assets/image.png">
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<div class="logo"></div>

.logo {
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:url('assets/image.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so far this is the only solution that solves the problem. Though I would still like to know how to fix the img problem, because this means I can never use an img in my program...please check the update in my question

Answer (score 3):

So the problem is that the angular project was lying in a location where it was causing an error. In my case it was lying in a bitbucket repository. I am not sure if that is the reason for the error though.

Try moving the whole angular project to a different location. That solved it for me :)

@Rak2018's solution is a good workaround if you would like to use that instead

Answer (score 3):

it's because of you don't have permission to access file.

**simple way in windows**
Move your project from drive C: to other drive. it's work fine.

Good luck.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I just encountered it and this answer helped me. Can anyone explain why this has to be this way?

Answer (score 2):

Try this `<img class="logo" src="./assets/image.png">`

also right click your picture and check if the extension is PNG instead of png, if so write image.PNG

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I tried this but it does not seem to solve the problem.

Comment: @frank I have read the update, the only thing that comes to my mind is that its either user's permission on the PC, an antivirus/firewall either blocking request/directory or image. Since the code is valid and works fine on the other PC.

Answer (score 2):

Following other tutorials on the web, I created a `src\app\assets\images` folder and put my image there.  However, my app already had an assets folder in `src\assets`.  There are two fixes to this.

Either:

1. Put my image in the existing `src\assets` folder and reference as `<img src="src\assets\my-image.png"/>` or
2. Add `src\app\assets` to my angular.json assets declaration and reference as was my original intention of `src\app\assets\images\my-image.png`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as well. and for me was to add a '/' before the assests directory:

Answer (score 0):

If it's due to case-sensitivity in URLs hosted by 'ng serve', there is an option to disable that. 'ng serve' uses webpack-dev-server which uses http-proxy-middleware. You can write a custom middleware script which corrects the url-case to match the file-case (it only affects the server response, the browser still sees the original url).

An example of how to code that is posted here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/578#issuecomment-569121500

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to parentheses in your workspace path if you're using an old version of Angular: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56736932/4179032. (I tried it in Angular 12.2.8 and it's fixed in that at least.)

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue, this has turned out to be a case sensitive issue on the path.

In my case image folder under assets was in capital I on the image folder. /assets/Images/angularconnect-shield.png

so check, your image path and make sure it is exactly matching with.