# Angular 7+ : Images in assets folder does not appear

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Info about my Angular version:
Angular CLI: 7.3.9

```
Node: 10.15.3   
OS: win32 x64   
Angular: 7.2.15   
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms   
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic    
... router
```

**Issue** that I'm facing is:

In dev build/environment:
Images in Angular's `assets` folder does not appear.
When you check the path it shows up as "http://localhost:4200/assets/sample.jpg" with HTTP error 404 (Not Found).
In HTML template it is written as
`<img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="assets/sample.jpg">`
sample.jpg lies in this folder `myapp/src/assets/sample.jpg`

In prod build/environment:
`assets` folder does not get compiled and generated in the `dist` folder itself hence, it does not appear here as well.

This is the case with even a fresh project generated from Angular CLI. This also happens with the favicon.

This is my `assets` array under `build` and `test` in `angular.json`.

```
    "assets": [
      "src/favicon.ico",
      "src/assets"
    ],
```

I verified my file name and path.
Tried creating a couple of isolated projects on the same machine.

**PS:**
Now I'm starting to doubt whether it is due to some machine restriction. I'm working on a machine with limited user access setup. Could this be the reason? Any system level restriction can prevent images from loading?

Comment: make sure you've added "src/assets" to the assets array in angular.json file.

Comment: Its already there as it comes in a new default angular scaffolding app generated by angular cli. My question also updated with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temp O'rary: this definitely could be an access rights issue, and from everything I read, it probably is. I say that because you mention *assets folder does not get compiled and generated in the dist folder itself*.

Try creating or moving your project to a different drive. E.g. Frank's comment at [Angular 6 Failing To Load Images From Assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50843655/angular-6-failing-to-load-images-from-assets) describes him storing his code in BitBucket, which was causing him what sounds like the same issue that you're experiencing.

It also sounds like you've enough a tech background to know that case sensitivity in file can affect things, but... since you're using the CLI to generate the project, I'm thinking you should at least be seeing assets in the compiled version, and hence that this is probably not the issue here.

Comment: Yes, it worked on a machine with lesser to no restriction which is why I doubted this possibility. Granting +1 for confirming my suspicion. Definitely the IT has something blocked which is turning into a hindrance. But I will need to identify and present it before them to believe and remove whatever is blocking it. Can you help me how can I identify this? What in a system would block innocent png/jpg images on localhost?

Comment: Finally from the clue that you gave, I was able to identify the issue. My project files were in my Dropbox folder (which is integrated with my file explorer) which is why it prevented the images from appearing. Thank you. Please update your answer with this.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding './' in front of assets/...

```
<img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="./assets/sample.jpg">
```

Comment: Can you please share your whole _angular.json_ file.   And a screenshot about your project tree.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the assets declared in `angular.json`:
Under architect --> build:

```
architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
```

Comment: Its already there as it comes in a new default angular scaffolding app generated by angular cli. My question also updated with this.

Comment: try using the image src as relative: `src="assets/images/logo.png"` Also what value  do you have in `root` in angular.json?

Comment: "projects": {
    "myapp": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src", 

I checked the path it is correct (updated my question with explanation to this)

Answer (score 0):

Want a background image?  this works.

```
src
--app
  --customComponent
--assets
```

in customComponent.css

```
:host{
  background-image : url("~src/assets/equaljustice.PNG");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
<img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="../../assets/sample.jpg">
```

each "../" is referring to one directory before your current directory. for example, if you are in src/app/someComponent you must use "../../assets to get access to your assets directory because assets and src are in the same directory.

Comment: may I see your directory structure?